# save xml file results in System.UnauthorizedAccessException:

Tags: c#, xml, windows, iis-7

I am trying to save xml to a certain location like this:

```
private void UpdateXMLFile(XElement xmlFeed,string xmlFileLocation)
{
            xmlFeed.Save(xmlFileLocation);
}
```

I have added SYSTEM, NETWORK SERVICE and Administrators all with all permissions to the folder I am saving in but I still get this error?

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path 'c:\temp\myfile.xml' is denied
```

I am using an asp.net 3.5 application (iis 7) to do this. The identity of the application is the 'ApplicatonPoolIdentity'

Comment: What type of authetication you got?

Comment: @Garath see comments above

Answer (score 2):

you need to add write permissions for user **IIS APPPOOL\[your app pool name]** to that folder. This user is created "under the hood" when you create an app pool, and you can find them in your "local users" manager:

[image: "local users" manager]

Answer (score 0):

In my options there are two possibilities:

1. You did not grant write permission to IIS APPPOOL user. The problems can occur when you have non-Windows integrated authentication enaled in Web.Config
2. You have to grant write permission to every user which is using your site if you have Windows integrated authentication